# Average every four two dimensional numpy arrays python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

If I have a numpy array like this (8 two dimensional sub arrays):

```
 array([[[1, 1, 1], 
         [1, 1, 1]],

        [[2, 2, 2], 
         [2, 2, 2]], 

        [[1, 1, 1], 
         [1, 1, 1]], 

        [[2, 2, 2], 
         [2, 2, 2]], 

        [[3, 3, 3], 
         [3, 3, 3]], 

        [[4, 4, 4], 
         [4, 4, 4]], 

        [[3, 3, 3], 
         [3, 3, 3]], 

        [[4, 4, 4], 
         [4, 4, 4]]])
```

How do I average every four two dimensional arrays such that I get a new array that looks like this:

```
 array([[[1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
         [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]],
        [[3.5, 3.5, 3.5], 
         [3.5, 3.5, 3.5]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the first axis into two with the length of the second one being `4` resulting in `n+1-dim` array and then get average along that one -

```
# a is the input array
In [42]: a.reshape((-1,4)+a.shape[1:]).mean(1)
Out[42]: 
array([[[1.5, 1.5, 1.5],
        [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]],

       [[3.5, 3.5, 3.5],
        [3.5, 3.5, 3.5]]])
```